# Time domain to angular domain approach

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, python, time-domain

I have a rotating shaft where I need to move from the time domain to the angular domain to look for vibration faults. I have the data from a tachometer.

From another [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42345/time-synchronous-averaging-matlab) I found these steps:

> **The steps involved for time domain --> Angle domain are:**
>
> 1. Use the tachometer signal to obtain a speed signal. This is the
>      inverse of the difference in time for each trigger point.
> 2. Depending
>      upon the variability of the tachometer signal least squares cubic
>      spline fitting is often used. Matlab spline library will work as will
>      matlab central libraries. I use the fastBspline library.
> 3. Integrate the
>      speed signal to obtain shaft angle position.
> 4. Determine the equal angle
>      increments that you want to use. Keep the Nyquist theorum in mind, in
>      other words there should be roughly the same number of points in the
>      angle domain as in the time domain.
> 5. Switch the (time, angle) data to
>      (angle, time). Resample the (angle, time) data to obtain uniform angle
>      increments. Once this is done, do all the same processing you would
>      have done, but now you are in the angle order domain.

**Questions**

**In regards to step 2:** What is returned if I integrate the speed signal (which is an array)? Surely that would not be a function or an array?

**In regards to step 5:** Why is it necessary to change from (time, angle) to (angle,time)? How is this plot related to the original vibration signal (time, acceleration)?

Comment: I suggest you put some sample data to really illustrate what you are asking. For example, in (time, angle), which is the independent signal and which is dependent signal.

Comment: For integrator, you can look for accumulator. The output is also an array. It gives the sum of inputs till that point. $y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1} x[k]$